# How do I use the debugging symbols in libc6-dbg with pstack?

Tags: debug-symbols, pstack

I have libc6-dbg installed, but pstack still says:

(No symbols found in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)

How do I tell it where to find the symbols?